springboot 3.3.1 user pulsar plugin @PulsarListener with KeySharedPolicySticky policy question
I try to use @PulsarListener springboot 3.3.1 Component to use SubscriptionType.Key_Shared to consumer data with two different consumer service, need to consumer with with different key please see code
produce part:
@Service

@Slf4j
public class PulsarDemoProductionImpl implements PulsarDemoProduction {
@Autowired
private PulsarTemplate<String> pulsarTemplate;

//    @Autowired
//    private PulsarTemplate pulsarTemplateList;
private static final String TOPIC = "real-time-data";

@Override
public void sendPulsarData(int triggerTimes) {
    //组装数据
    for(int i = 0; i < triggerTimes; i++) {
        RealTimeDTO realTimeDTO = loadData();
        //转成json字符串
        String realTimeDataJson = JSON.toJSONString(realTimeDTO);
        long timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        log.info("Sending timeStamp = {} real time data via Pulsar: {}",  timeStamp, realTimeDataJson);
        if (i%2 == 0) {
            //发送数据
            pulsarTemplate.newMessage(realTimeDataJson)
                    .withTopic(TOPIC)
                    .withMessageCustomizer((message) -> message.key("data"))
                    .withSchema(Schema.JSON(String.class))
                    .sendAsync();
        } else {
            //发送数据
            pulsarTemplate.newMessage(realTimeDataJson)
                    .withTopic(TOPIC)
                    .withMessageCustomizer((message) -> message.key("state"))
                    .withSchema(Schema.JSON(String.class))
                    .sendAsync();
        }

        //pulsarTemplate.sendAsync(TOPIC, realTimeDataJson, Schema.JSON(String.class));

    }

    log.info("Sending real time data via Pulsar");
}



private RealTimeDTO loadData() {
    //生成时间的时间戳
    Instant instant = Instant.now();
    long mills = instant.toEpochMilli();

    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

    return RealTimeDTO.builder()
            .uuid(UUID.fastUUID().toString())
            .data(RealTimeData.builder().speed(decimalFormat.format(Math.random() * 10)).build())
            .timestamp(String.valueOf(mills))
            .build();
}

}
consumer part:
@Service

@Slf4j
public class PulsarDemoConsumeImpl implements PulsarDemoConsume {
private static final String TOPIC = "real-time-data";



@Override
@PulsarListener(topics = TOPIC,
        subscriptionName = "real-time-data-consumer",
        subscriptionType = SubscriptionType.Key_Shared,
        schemaType = SchemaType.JSON,
        ackMode = AckMode.MANUAL,
        concurrency = "5",
        consumerCustomizer = @KeySharedPolicy(
                KeySharedPolicy.KeySharedPolicySticky.class,
                ranges = {"0x00000000-0x7FFFFFFF", "0x80000000-0xFFFFFFFF"}),
        ackTimeoutRedeliveryBackoff = "redeliveryBackoff")
public void handleRedeliveryBackOff(Message<String> message, Acknowledgement acknowledgement) {
    log.info("real-time-data-consumer key = {} from Pulsar: {}", message.getKey(), message.getValue());
    acknowledgement.acknowledge();
}

}
however @PulsarListener annotation currently not involved KeySharedPolicy.KeySharedPolicySticky propeties
how to complete that requirement, any idea
I try use AI give me a tip however it fails
enter image description here

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
